# Bayesian update approach for quantum phase estimation query

Tags: quantum-information, computational-physics, simulations, quantum-measurements

**Bayesian Estimation Approach for Quantum Phase Estimation:**

I am interested if my understanding of the iterative method for Bayesian quantum phase estimation is correct before producing computational models thereof. Any comments, corrections and discussion will be appreciated, thanks.

- Encode the true phase $\phi$ by some unitary operator $\hat{U}_{\phi}$ acting on some quantum state $|\psi\rangle$, i.e., $\hat{U}_{\phi}|\psi\rangle$. This encoded $\phi$ is the assumed true phase $\phi$ that we want to estimate.
- Consider a set of measurement operators (such as photon counting measurements). Using a random number generator we simulate the quantum measurement process $\nu$ times and record the set of measurement outcomes.
- Assume some prior distribution $p(\phi)$ (maybe uniform or Gaussian distribution). After each round of simulated quantum measurement, we update the posterior using **Baye's rule**: $$p(\phi|m)=\frac{p(m|\phi)p(\phi)}{\int_{\Phi} p(m|\phi)p(\phi) d\phi},$$
  where $p(m|\phi)$ is the Likelihood function, and the denominator is the normalization constant. The Likelihood function is determined by the chosen true value of $\phi$, the quantum measurement probabilities and measurement outcomes from the data collected. For example a quantum measurement with three possible outcomes {$m_1, m_2, m_3$} and respective probabilities {$p_1, p_2, p_3$}, has Likelihood function defined $p(m|\phi) := p_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}p_3^{m_3}$ for every given round of measurement and update. Using a random number generator we would produce quantum measurement outcomes of the form {{1,0,0}, {0,1,0},...}.
- We then consider some estimator $\hat{\phi}$ definition, such as the mean of the posterior distribution $\hat{\phi}:=\int_{\Phi}\phi p(\phi|m) d \phi$, or the maximum a posterior estimator (MAP) defined by $\hat{\phi}_{MAP} := \text{arg}~\text{max}_{\phi}~p(\phi|m)$. After each round where the posterior is updated, we compute the estimator $\hat{\phi}$.
- We then compute a suitable Loss Function such as the squared difference $$L(\phi, \hat{\phi}) := (\phi - \hat{\phi})^2,$$ and consider how many measurement iterations $\nu$ results in a suitable convergence to the true $\phi$ value.